# What does "CLR Thread 0x25e @ RDI" mean?

Tags: .net, windbg

This is in the output of the `!refs -target 000000951d7df438` SOSEX command. I interpret it as "the RDI register on the CLR thread 0x25e holds the value 000000951d7df438". However, examining the dump does not confirm this statement.

Please, observe:

```
0:000> !refs -target 000000951d7df438
Objects that reference 000000951D7DF438 (Ā䟋):
  CLR Thread 0x25e @ RDI
  NONE
0:000> ? 0x25e
Evaluate expression: 606 = 00000000`0000025e
0:000> .shell -ci "!threads" find /i "606"
 109  606 18c0 00000097a43a3df0  1029220 Preemptive  0000009B4980DF10:0000009B4980F010 000000934776c5e0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
.shell: Process exited
0:000> ~109r
rax=00007fff58d37648 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000009b497fea20
rdx=0000000000000014 rsi=00000000ffffffff rdi=000000000000019c
rip=00007fff76ae06fa rsp=000000978a45c508 rbp=0000000000003e98
 r8=0000009b497fd5b0  r9=0000000000001438 r10=0000009b4980f010
r11=00000097a43a3df0 r12=0000000000000000 r13=00000093477a7a10
r14=0000000000000000 r15=00000093477a7a10
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa:
00007fff`76ae06fa c3              ret
0:000> .shell -ci "~*r" find /i "000000951d7df438"
.shell: Process exited
```

As you can see, in the last command I scan the output of the `r` command ran across all the threads. None register across any threads has the value of `000000951d7df438`

So, I do not understand what `CLR Thread 0x25e @ RDI` truly means. What does it mean?

Comment: Could it be a reference to the rdi register of the mentioned thread?

Comment: That's what I thought - please see the post body where I show the output of windbg commands showing that it is not.

Comment: any reason for converting hex 25e to decimal 606 and using it if you need to specify decimal does providing 0n606 work find works on strings so it may not find 606 try 25e as is in find command. does providing 25e to thread command work. what is minus 109 is it tilde 109

Comment: Could you check what's in the registers of that thread across all frames? I think RDI holds that value but in an earlier frame.

Comment: Good point. I will. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - are you saying registers are saved per thread stack frame? This is new to me.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - according to my memory registers are not preserved across the frames. It is the code's responsibility to preserve the used registers on the stack before calling another function. Indeed, running `r @rdi` for all the frames on the thread 109 yields the same value. Could you elaborate on your suggestion?

Comment: I ended up running `!mk -a` and searching for the address in question - 000000951d7df438. Found the respective frame and continued from there. How `refs` decided the value on the stack actually belongs to the RDI register is a mystery for me.

Comment: In x86 they were pushed to the stack, weren't they? In x64 things are difficult

Comment: From my distant x86 assembly programming years I do not recollect it. I think registers were never preserved per stack frame.